# Do I need a lot of money to make music?

Tags: software, electronic-music, production

I am just a little kid who really likes music. I have been producing EDM House and Dubstep for about 6 months. I use a free software called [LMMS](https://lmms.io/) with my Dad's laptop and no MIDI keyboard. I also use some $40 headphones. This is just my hobby, so I can't really invest a lot of money on this. Can I still make good music? By "good," I mean NCS music that people would actually listen to. Just buying [FL Studio](https://www.image-line.com/flstudio/) can cost $200. Do I really need those expensive products? I know it will be beneficial, but is it worth it and is it necessary?

Thank you :-)

Comment: If you can't make music that people want to listen to with a laptop, some free software, and some $40 headphones, spending $200, $2,000, or even $20,000 won't change that situation. Just remember that probably 99% of people who "want to make music people want to listen to" never succeed - not because they don't have enough money, but because they don't have enough *talent*.

Comment: Totally agree with alephzero! Don't fall for the trap that the more expensive price tag means better music. Better music comes from the musician, not from the tech. I purchased some odd $300+ dollars of equipment and my music making ability was the same. It only progressed with practice and study (boring answer right :P well, not if you love music). SO, you don't need a lot of money, but you do need a lot of patience and time to develop your gift in music. Then hey, maybe we all will be hearing your music in movies or on the radio. Who knows :)

Comment: I'd have to absolutely support aleph and Briard on this. Tools can help but they create nothing. Only you can do that. Additionally, FL Studio is one of the cheapest tools... So if it seems expensive to you, stop focusing on tools.

Comment: How old are you, by the way?

Comment: I've seen people make exceptionally great music on a cheap laptop with MilkyTracker. In the UK some artists have had chart topping hits making music with a cheap MIDI controller and a bog standard laptop (T2 for example. I know him). You can have all the gear and still no idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're getting started, then there is no reason to invest a lot of money in your hobby. Producing is like a discipline or like learning an instrument. For example, if you practise the drums for 6 months, you will be able to play some limited grooves and read rhythms, but you will be far away from being an actual drummer. Furthermore, you don't know how long you will stick (sic) at this hobby.

First, push your abilities to the limit. Gear won't make you a better musician. It can assist your existing skills, but won't make you a better producer. Experiment with your existing tools. I am pretty sure that you can still find out new things, as far as you have fun playing with them. Being limited can push your skills much more further than having a lot of expensive tools. Don't try to be especially "mainstream". Find your own style, be experimental, enjoy the art of making music.

A good software choice for beginners is Magix Music Maker. There is a free version available and you can upgrade cheaply at any given time.

Being able to make "good" music (good is always subjective) will cost you many many years.

Answer (score 6):

Well, there is that apocryphal story about Hemingway asking a photographer he admired which brand of camera he was using for making his pictures.  The photographer asked in return which brand of typewriter Hemingway employed for writing his stories.

Expensive stuff is great for working with recipes.  One-man bands can make good use of good arrangers, and they come in handy for serial production of stock music styles.

Basically, they allow you to focus your creativity on where you want and provide all the rest.

Basically they are akin to what Picasso stated: "Computers are useless: they only provide answers."

Creativity is more about developing your own "questions" and approaches to them.  If you want to be an entertainer, at one point of time there is good return for invested money.  If you want to be a composer and music creator, you might be better off not overindulging on equipment that already has a mind of its own distilled into it.

Answer (score 4):

What a nice question :) If I may, I would suggest that you can make music even with a stick hitting on a bucket. I think, at a first place, no budget or nothing whatsoever can limit your creative urge. Of course, if you have the good tools, which usually cost something, you can create more easily, but the essential thing one should have at very first place is the music inside. We as musicians/artists are transmitters of something higher than us, call it inspiration, joy, divine energy, etc. Whom do we transmit it to? Others. And I personally like that you aim at creating music that people would listen to. This is the creator's mission, namely to create something people would love listening, observing, to let them dream and disconnect from day-to-day bullshit.

So, back to the point, if I may suggest: 1) Ask yourself what music really turns YOU on; 2) Focus on that feeling and again ask yourself how you can transmit it to others with what you have NOW in your hands; 3) Do you really need tools and if so, why exactly and what for? How would a tool help you? What do you want to achieve and why?

I find a good and easy-to-use music making tool Garage Band that comes with a Mac and you don't need to pay additionally for it. It is also available for iPhone/iPad for free. And in this article they list TOP 5 free linux music creation tools: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/top-5-free-linux-music-creation-tools-artist-budget/. It is probably worth taking a look.

Good luck!

PS: I'm adding here the link from my comment below to some cool stick-bucket stuff with apparently millions of fans :)